# How to make a triangle with one angle being 90°

Tags: modeling

Im new to Blender and having troubles making a triangle with one angle being 90 degrees. I'm able to make a triangle but that's the existent of what I can do.

[image]

What I tried was making a normal triangle and attaching a cube to one side of it accomplishing what I want but this means I couldn't extend out side A (reference to image above) which is my goal.

Any other methods I should try?

End goal:

[image]

**(but 3D)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second screenshot of your desired result is the side view of the future prism, then you can dissolve geometry of the cube.

Add a cube, in Edit mode choose *Edge Select* to select edges. Select one of the top edges of the cube. Press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.

[image: screenshot-cube-gets-tortured]

[image: screenshot-hoorah]

Once the edge is dissolved the mesh becomes a prism.

Answer (score 2):

### Steps:

[image: Final]

1. Create a **Plane**.
2. Go to **Edit Mode**.
3. **Select All** - <kbd>A</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - to **Triangulate face**.
5. Delete one of the corner vertices.
6. **Select All** again - <kbd>A</kbd>.
7. <kbd>E</kbd> to **Extrude Plane** to 3D object.